# 3 layers architecture: Business layer in C# with joined table

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 tables and they are joined in Data Access Layer:
DAL

```
class TransDetailDAO
{
   private dbConnection conn;
    public TransDetailDAO()
    {
        conn = new dbConnection();
    }
    public DataTable SearchById(string transId)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblTransDetail INNER JOIN tblTransAction ON tblTransDetail.transId = tblTransAction.transId WHERE transId = '@transId'");
        OleDbParameter[] oleDbParameter = new OleDbParameter[1];
        oleDbParameter[0] = new OleDbParameter("@transId", OleDbType.VarChar);
        oleDbParameter[0].Value = Convert.ToString(transId);
        return conn.ExecuteSelectQuery(query,oleDbParameter);
    }
```

and the folder VO contains 2 class:

```
 class TransDetail
{
    private int _Id;
    private string _TransId;
    private string _GoodsId;
    private string _ExStoreId;
    private string _ImStoreId;
    private string _UnitId;
    private float _Amount;
    private float _Dispercent;
    private int _Quantities;
    private string _TransTime;
    private bool _Status;
    public TransDetail()
    {

    }
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }
    public string TransId
    {
        get { return _TransId; }
        set { _TransId = value; }
    }
    public string GoodsId
    {
        get { return _GoodsId; }
        set { _GoodsId = value; }
    }
    public string ExStoreId
    {
        get { return _ExStoreId; }
        set { _ExStoreId = value; }
    }
    public string ImStoreId
    {
        get { return _ImStoreId; }
        set { _ImStoreId = value; }
    }
    public string UnitId
    {
        get { return _UnitId; }
        set { _UnitId = value; }
    }
    public float Amount
    {
        get { return _Amount; }
        set { _Amount = value; }
    }
    public float Dispercent
    {
        get { return _Dispercent; }
        set { _Dispercent = value; }
    }
    public int Quantities
    {
        get { return _Quantities; }
        set { _Quantities = value; }
    }
    public string TransTime
    {
        get { return _TransTime; }
        set { _TransTime = value; }
    }
    public bool Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set { _Status = value; }
    }

}
class TransAction
{
    private string _TransId;
    private string _TransCode;
    private string _TransType;
    private DateTime _TransDate;
    private int _UserId;
    private float _TransAmount;
    private float _TransDiscount;
    private bool _Status;
    public TransAction()
    {

    }
    public string TransId
    {
        get { return _TransId; }
        set { _TransId = value; }
    }
    public string TransCode
    {
        get { return _TransCode; }
        set { _TransCode = value; }
    }
    public string TransType
    {
        get { return _TransType; }
        set { _TransType = value; }
    }
    public DateTime TransDate
    {
        get { return _TransDate; }
        set { _TransDate = value; }
    }
    public int UserId
    {
        get { return _UserId; }
        set { _UserId = value; }
    }
    public float TransAmount
    {
        get { return _TransAmount; }
        set { _TransAmount = value; }
    }
    public float TransDiscount
    {
        get { return _TransDiscount; }
        set { _TransDiscount = value; }
    }
    public bool Status
    {
        get { return _Status; }
        set { _Status = value; }
    }
}
```

How can I return joined table into value object(VO) in Business Layer? 
Should I create a class that contains all properties of 2 table?
How can it be if I have more than 1 Joined table?

Comment: You need to create a class in business layer, with properties, fields and methods. Create an instance for that class in business layer and send to a method in Data access layer. Populate the object in data access layer method and return to biz layer.

Comment: Where exactly is the "bus" in all this?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: the class you return may propably be your business object. There are many approaces on how to design these. you may have a look at the cleancoder webcasts they have some nice explanations. i would recommend start with episode 15 see https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-15/show